# Get the title from the pages table

Tags: php, symfony1

How do I use Doctrine in Symfony to get page title from a table of pages?

For example:

```
$title = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->getTitle($this->page_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the object and then pull the title from it.

Try:

```
$object = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->find($this->page_id);
$title = $object->getTitle();
```